ThingsBoard Edge: Issue Changing Originator from Device to Tenant in Rule Chain
Description:
I am working on a rule chain in ThingsBoard Edge (Professional Edition version from early 2024) and ThingsBoard Cluod which is atm v3.7. I need to change the originator of telemetry messages from a device to the tenant for saving state attribute. I am using the "Change Originator" transformation node to accomplish this. However, I am encountering a critical issue that prevents the rule chain from working as expected. I use
Problem:
When I configure the "Change Originator" node to change the originator from the device to the tenant:

I receive the following error on start:

org.thingsboard.rule.engine.api.TbNodeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't convert value: {"originatorSource":"TENANT","preserveOriginatorIfCustomer":false,"entityType":null,"entityNamePattern":null,"relationsQuery":{"direction":"FROM","maxLevel":1,"filters":[{"relationType":"Contains","entityTypes":[],"negate":false}],"fetchLastLevelOnly":false}}
    at org.thingsboard.rule.engine.api.util.TbNodeUtils.convert(TbNodeUtils.java:61)
    ...
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "preserveOriginatorIfCustomer" (class org.thingsboard.rule.engine.transform.TbChangeOriginatorNodeConfiguration), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "relationsQuery", "entityNamePattern", "entityType", "originatorSource"])
    ...

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with the "Change Originator" node in ThingsBoard? What could be causing the UnrecognizedPropertyException related to preserveOriginatorIfCustomer? Are there any workarounds or specific configurations required to successfully change the originator from a device to the tenant?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[Update] Change of originator works for me only on cloud rule chains not on edge instance.
